# WooCommerce - Add to cart without variation id

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have made a simple plugin what makes step by step selection for a user to choose a product he wants. It uses 4 steps, of which 3 are attributes selections. Now the issue I have come across is that direct link requires variation_id.
Generated link for product:

```
/cart/?add-to-cart=3772&attribute_pa_izmers=20&attribute_pa_forma=kaste&attribute_pa_krasas=spilgtas
```

In order for the following link to work, I need also pass variation_id. However, I cannot find a way to acquire it without manually passing every single variation_id combination. Is there a hook/action I can use to acquire variation id based on attributes I pass? Or add the product to cart without passing variation id?

I have already asked on woocommerce forums but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you tell me where to insert the below code which you accepted as correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could borrow some code from the `WC_Ajax::get_variation()` method since that runs when you use select the attributes for a normal variable product.

```
$data_store   = WC_Data_Store::load( 'product' );
$variation_id = $data_store->find_matching_product_variation( $variable_product, wp_unslash( $_POST ) );
```

Requires WooCommerce 3.0+

Comment: It's not a cut and paste answer, but rather a suggestion. It would depend on how you need to use it and the full answer would depend on your code.